# HTTP Post to PHP file to query database and return array based on query. Swift

Tags: php, sql, swift

I have a SQL database that I have been able to pull and display in a table view. I have a simple PHP script that queries and returns the database. Right now the query variables are hard coded in the PHP file but I need to be able to modify the query from the app. I believe I need to use http post requests for this.

I have posted below the PHP file and the view controller file in their entirety.

First the PHP.

```
 <?php

$config = parse_ini_file("config_files/config.ini"); 
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost",$config["username"],$config["password"],$config["dbname"]);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

 // This added as my attempt to do POST. Before I just had 9 in the query where I have the variable $user_id_app_sent_int. 
$user_id_app_sent = $_REQUEST['user_id_app'];

// I did this (int) conversion because I think it is receiving form the app as a string?
$user_id_app_sent_int = (int)$user_id_app_sent;


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `invoice` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id_app_sent_int";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Now for the swift file.

```
import UIKit

class InvoiceListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    // Custom Variable
    var invoiceData = [NSDictionary]()
    var arrayCount = Int()

    // Table View Outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()






        // This is the main pull data section.
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/service.php")!

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            // This is my attempt.

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/service.php")!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let postString = "user_id_app=9"
            request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                data, response, error in

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                print("response = \(response)")

            }

            task.resume()

            // end post test attempt. If this section is removed, and I return the hardcoded value to the PHP file, it works fine for pulling and displaying the database data.


            if let invoiceWebData = data{ // Open if let

                do {

                    let invoiceDataPulled = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(invoiceWebData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [NSDictionary]

                    self.invoiceData = invoiceDataPulled
                    self.arrayCount = self.invoiceData.count

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    })


                } // Close Do 

                catch {

                    print("JSON Serialization Failed")

                }

            } // Close If Let

        } // Close Task

        task.resume()


    } // Close View Did Load

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(invoiceData)
        return arrayCount


    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("invoiceCell") as! InvoiceCell

        let row = indexPath.row

        let rowData: NSDictionary = invoiceData[row]

        let userLogIn: String? = (rowData["user_id"] as? String)

        if let logInUnwrapped = userLogIn {

            cell.cellNameLabel.text = logInUnwrapped

        } 

        return cell

    }
}
```

So basically, I want to send a query variable to make the PHP file query and return specific portions of the database.

Comment: actually, I checked your code, and your PHP part seems fine. What exactly does not work? Do you receive data into $_REQUEST?

Comment: I think my Swift side might is wrong. See the part where I say // This is my attempt.

Comment: you should use the following code to see what exactly you receive
<?php
file_put_contents ( 'log.txt' , print_r($_REQUEST, true));

Comment: I tried both things, but I couldn't see any results.

From Xcode I get the following in the console, which is an out put of 'response'

    response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7bc9b920> { URL: http://localhost:8888/service.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 325;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Tue, 01 Sep 2015 12:59:14 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=98";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.6.2 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zg DAV/2..... etc.

Comment: actually you should open log.txt at the same level as you php file to see what data has been sent by your app. Can you paste here the output?

Answer (score 0):

in PHP all the post data is to be found in the $_POST super variable.
In your app you are sending `"user_id_app=9"`.

In PHP you should then have:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['user_id_app'];
// output 9
```

Since there is no protection against sql injections in your script I strongly advise you to cast the data:

```
<?php
// if user_id_app received by post, cast value to integer otherwise default to 0
$user_id_app = isset($_POST['user_id_app']) ? intval($_POST['user_id_app']): 0;
```

There are more elegant ways of doing things but this should be enough for your need at this stage.